# Converting a Raw g722 File to a .wav with SOX

Tags: audio, wireshark, sox

I am trying to troubleshoot some VOIP issues, and have been capturing the packets for the trouble calls.  However my calls are all encoded in g722 and I am having trouble decoding this.

I have extracted the RTP payload, and have it currently as a raw file.  The only information I can find is this link:

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/26607/coverting-g722-payload-to-wav

But I cant seem to figure out how to get the g722 raw to a usable wave file.  Any points in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I've been down the same track as well.  What I found was that SOX doesn't support g722!! I ended up having to write my own converter :(

Comment: @ShanePowell  Any chance you want to share with the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, SOX doesn't support g722.

I ended up creating my own converter using internal codec support within the company I work for.  For this reason I can't release that version.

I then re-wrote it using the open source library [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/).

You can find it here: https://github.com/shanepowell/G722Converter

You can download a compiled version here: https://github.com/shanepowell/G722Converter/releases/latest

It requries the [.net framework v4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) to be installed to run.

Answer (score 5):

FFMPEG works well,  but the suggested arguments do not work. I used:

```
ffmpeg  -f g722 -i input.raw -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 output.wav
```

Options applying to input files should precede the file name, using `.wav` on the output file defines the format.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG can do the job as well

```
ffmpeg -i g722_input_file.raw -f g722 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 out.pcm
```